# Validate if one date is before another with Zod Resolver

Tags: validation, react-hook-form, zod

We are working on a Next.js app which is using react-hook-form and Zod Resolver. Here's the minified version of the issue with omitted irrelevant details:

We have two different forms for user details. In one form we have the fields for the birth date and the date since when the user is employed. In another form we have the field for the date since when the user lives in the country. I need to make a validation if the latter dates (`employedSince` and `residentSince`) are not before the `birthDate`.

We don't know if the fields will be moved between the forms in the future, so we defined one "common" validation schema with all the fields:

```
export const commonSchema = z.object({
  birthDate: z.string();
  employedSince: z.string();
  residentSince: z.string();
  /* ...other fields... */
});

export type CommonSchema = z.infer<typeof commonSchema>;
```

Then we pick the fields which we need for each form:

```
export const firstSchema = commonSchema.pick({
  birthDate: true,
  residentSince: true,
  /* ... */
});

export const secondSchema = commonSchema.pick({
  employedSince: true,
  /* ... */
});

export type FirstSchema = z.infer<typeof firstSchema>;
export type SecondSchema = z.infer<typeof secondSchema>;
```

In both form components, we are defining default values for certain fields and the form object itself:

```
import pick from 'lodash.pick';

const savedData = getDataFromDB();
const firstFormDefaults = useMemo(
  () => pick(savedData, Object.keys(firstSchema.shape)),
  [savedData],
);

const firstForm = useForm<Partial<FirstSchema>>({
   defaultValues: { ...firstFormDefaults },
   resolver: zodResolver(firstSchema),
});
```

...and we do exactly the same thing for the second form.

**Question:** What would be the easiest way (i.e. without too much refactoring and changing of the existing code) to validate if `employedSince` and `residentSince` are *not* before the `birthDate`?

**What I have tried so far:**

- Using `.superRefine()` on the `commonSchema`, where I validated the dates. The problem is that by using `superRefine`, my schema becomes a `ZodEffect` and not a `ZodObject` anymore, and then I can't call `.pick()` on it anymore.
- Making a "validated" schema out of a "normal" one and then calling `.merge()` to put them together, but it didn't work as well (maybe it *is* the right way but I just didn't implement it correctly)
- Having a separate function which will perform schema validation and "wrapping" the schema in it. That solved the issue with `.pick()` (I was able to call it again), but I didn't have the `shape` anymore and I got an error on the line `pick(savedData, Object.keys(firstSchema.shape))`
- Using `.parse` instead of `Object.keys(firstSchema.shape))`, but that didn't give me the expected result either

Some of these solutions were proposed by my colleagues, some other were proposed by ChatGPT (I don't want to say who proposed what :)), but apparently I'm still missing some tiny details to make everything work. Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this?